# ENS on Rinkeby - Network does not support ENS?

Tags: transactions, metamask, contract-invocation, etherscan, ens

I was able to register the ENS domain on Rinkeby, as the network supports ENS.

My TX: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xd42b64ab03387d7ca405e7ba7b85ce893444a141e7a7de174f0361e2c4231674

My subdomain: `testing.estoniadao.eth`

[image]

## Does it support or does it not?

Domain is registered: https://app.ens.domains/name/estoniadao.eth

Cannot lookup on Etherscan, cannot find any other blockchain explorer supporting Rinkeby.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ENS is deployed on Ropsten. Looks like an issue with metamask. Apparently this is a [feature, see their Github](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/pull/7944). However it still works on Ropsten.

Etherscan doesn't seem to support ENS names on testnets unfortunately.

Here's a [list of all ENS deployments across networks](https://docs.ens.domains/ens-deployments).

Comment: https://etherscan.io/contactus - messaged them asking to support Ropsten, that would save me a `$0.07` on gas testing various features... Without Etherscan flying blind!