# How to create the ENS subdomain and assign it to an address?

Tags: ens

The full code: https://plnkr.co/edit/WYDB9fOvmRoUvCVw

Testing on the mainnet because: [ENS on Rinkeby - Network does not support ENS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82780/ens-on-rinkeby-network-does-not-support-ens)

#### 1️⃣ `setSubnodeOwner` works

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfc88211f5ac3ca51dbcc9f39b6d00f4ce39c25febb248256bdc3925818c2e677

```
web3.eth.ens.('dearmoon.eth', 'hack', accounts[0], {from: accounts[0]}).then(function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt); 
});
```

#### 2️⃣ `setResolver` works

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x562c26d3770804586ba9a432dc8ad9e22b02956dc81c3aec72ddb89e28f908e8

```
web3.eth.ens.setResolver('hack.dearmoon.eth', '0x00000000000C2E074eC69A0dFb2997BA6C7d2e1e', {from: accounts[0]}).then(function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt);
});
```

#### 3️⃣ `setAddress` fails

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2f077a521c5824ebecd8e9306a3f96dc955ec7bcb4f18c8e9fc781f7498c6af9

*(Metamask told me it will fail but I send it anyway hoping for some helpful revert message)*

```
web3.eth.ens.setAddress('hack.dearmoon.eth', '0x614962025820c57d6af5acff56b5879237daf559', { from: accounts[0] }).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result.events);
});
```

I'm using: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.7/web3-eth-ens.html#setaddress

#### Do you know why `setAddress` fails? ‍♀️

---

#### Existing research, good links:

1. https://github.com/ensdomains/subdomain-registrar - not good, the transfer is irrevocable, I need flexibility.
2. https://www.toptal.com/dapp/ethereum-name-service-dapp-tutorial - this is actually quite clever, including smart contract that does everything in a single transaction: https://github.com/radek1st/ens-subdomain-factory/blob/master/contracts/EnsSubdomainFactory.sol#L73-L79

```
registry.setSubnodeOwner(domainNamehash, subdomainLabelhash, address(this));
registry.setResolver(subdomainNamehash, resolver);
resolver.setAddr(subdomainNamehash, _target);
registry.setOwner(subdomainNamehash, _owner);
```

I'm thinking about using it but before doing complicated stuff I prefer to learn basics first.

Longer-term I would like to anyone register a subdomain but without me losing ownership.

Answer (score 0):

**Super obvious.**

In step 2️⃣ should use the address of the public resolver: https://etherscan.io/address/0x4976fb03C32e5B8cfe2b6cCB31c09Ba78EBaBa41

From [Gitter](https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum/name-registry?at=5ea5628d1eb8bd3978f76eb9) chat:

[image]